# Having trouble understanding what's going on in these generics(?) definitions, incl. Type Argument Lists

Tags: typescript

I'm looking at this code, from the typescript definitions from fastify. I'm having trouble figuring out these definitions. I know the angle brackets are for generics, but the typescript tutorials are mainly for things like Array, not different classes. Also, several of these have more than one type separated by commas. Does the definition include all of them, or just a list to pick one from? The typescript spec talks about typed argument lists but doesn't give a good example. I'd appreciate someone telling me what's going on here.

```
this: FastifyInstance<HttpServer, HttpRequest, HttpResponse>,
req: FastifyRequest<HttpRequest, Query, Params, Headers, Body>,
reply: FastifyReply<HttpResponse>,
```

Comment: There are plenty of examples for generics, look at all the utilities https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html

Answer (score 1):

Generics are all about specifying how types are related to eachother, without dictating exactly what the types are. Fastify's type definitions are complex, so let me go through simpler examples.

Suppose i want to create an object that has 3 properties, a value, a getValue function, and a setValue function. I want this to work with any sort of type, so a first pass might be to stick a bunch of `any`s in there. But if i did that, i could create an object with getters and setters that are dealing with different types, and i don't want that.

I want to specify the relationships between the types, and that is done using a generic like this:

```
interface ValueHolder<T> {
  value: T,
  getValue: () => T,
  setValue: (val: T) => void
}
```

The `T` in the angle brackets is just a placeholder. I could name it anything i wanted; `T` was just a convention. What's important though is that every `T` is referring to the same type. I don't know what that type is yet, but i can tell typescript which parts of this object must be consistent with eachother.

If value is a `number`, then getValue is a function that returns a `number` and setValue is a function that accepts a `number`. Or if value is a `string[]`, then getValue returns a `string[]`, and setValue accepts a `string[]`. Any type can be slotted in for T, but typescript will enforce that i use the same type at all the relevant spots in the object.

Here's an example of using that interface:

```
const numberExample: ValueHolder<number> = {
  value: 2,
  getValue: function () {
    return this.value;
  },
  setValue: function (val: number) {
    this.value = 2;
  }
}
```

And typescript will verify and enforce that i'm using the identical type everywhere i'm supposed to.

---

For more complicated cases, it's sometimes necessary to have multiple placeholders. So rather than having one thing inside the angle brackets, you can have multiple, separated by commas. As before, the point is to then use these to describe how the types are related to eachother.

For example:

```
interface Converter<InputType, OutputType> {
  initialValue: InputType,
  mappingFunction: (val: InputType) => OutputType;
  calculateResult: () => OutputType;
}

const example: Converter<number, string> = {
  initialValue: 6,
  mappingFunction: function (val: number) {
    return (number + 1).toString();
  },
  calculateResult: function () {
    return this.mappingFunction(this.initialValue);
  }
}
```

---

As i mentioned, some of the fastify type definitions are complex, but it's basically a continuation of these principles. For example, it defines a type called `FastifyMiddleware`, and then it has 7 placeholder types: HttpServer, HttpRequest, HttpResponse, Query, Params, Headers, and Body. It also provides default values for these types, so you can omit them if necessary.

Following that, it describes in detail how these types are related to eachother. You can put anything you like in for these types, but typescript will ensure that you use them consistently.

Comment: So <HttpServer, HttpRequest, HttpResponse> is really no different than <T, U, V>. Got it.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a comment but I need the code formatting. Here's a full type definition from fastify. What does the equals signs, and the what's after, mean here?

```
type FastifyMiddleware<
HttpServer = http.Server,
HttpRequest = http.IncomingMessage,
HttpResponse = http.ServerResponse,
Query = DefaultQuery,
Params = DefaultParams,
Headers = DefaultHeaders,
Body = DefaultBody
> = (
  this: FastifyInstance<HttpServer, HttpRequest, HttpResponse>,
  req: FastifyRequest<HttpRequest, Query, Params, Headers, Body>,
  reply: FastifyReply<HttpResponse>,
  done: (err?: Error) => void,
) => void
```

Comment: The first 7 equal signs are for default types. You can specify all 7 yourself if you want, or you can omit however many you like and use the defaults. `FastifyMiddleware<number, string>` would specify that the HttpServer is a number, the HttpRequest is a string, and the rest are defaults